# Only Previous Button is Worked in NotificationCompat.MediaStyle() in android

Tags: java, android, layout, notifications

Only Previous Button is Worked in NotificationCompat.MediaStyle()  in android.
Why my next and pause button worked in android notification.

```
private void setMediaPlaybackState(int state) {
    PlaybackStateCompat.Builder playbackstateBuilder = new PlaybackStateCompat.Builder();
    if( state == PlaybackStateCompat.STATE_PLAYING ) {
        playbackstateBuilder.setActions(PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_PLAY_PAUSE | PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_PAUSE);
    } else {
        playbackstateBuilder.setActions(PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_PLAY_PAUSE | PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_PLAY);
    }
    playbackstateBuilder.setActions(PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_SKIP_TO_NEXT);
    playbackstateBuilder.setActions(PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_SKIP_TO_PREVIOUS);
    playbackstateBuilder.setState(state, PlaybackStateCompat.PLAYBACK_POSITION_UNKNOWN, 1);
    mMediaSessionCompat.setPlaybackState(playbackstateBuilder.build());
}

private void showPlayingNotification() {
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = MediaStyleHelper.from(BackgroundAudioService.this, mMediaSessionCompat);
    if( builder == null ) {
        return;
    }
    builder.addAction(new NotificationCompat.Action(R.drawable.ic_skip_previous_black_48dp, "Play", MediaButtonReceiver.buildMediaButtonPendingIntent(this, PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_SKIP_TO_PREVIOUS)));
    builder.addAction(new NotificationCompat.Action(R.drawable.ic_pause, "Pause", MediaButtonReceiver.buildMediaButtonPendingIntent(this, PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_PLAY_PAUSE)));
    builder.addAction(new NotificationCompat.Action(R.drawable.ic_skip_next_black_48dp, "Play", MediaButtonReceiver.buildMediaButtonPendingIntent(this, PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_SKIP_TO_NEXT)));
    builder.setStyle(new NotificationCompat.MediaStyle().setShowActionsInCompactView(0,1,2).setShowCancelButton(true).setMediaSession(mMediaSessionCompat.getSessionToken()));
    builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.music_logo);
    NotificationManagerCompat.from(BackgroundAudioService.this).notify(1, builder.build());
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I realize that this post is a little old, but I am going to answer with what I think your question is asking. You are saying that only the previous button works, but skip doesn't. My response to this is to do the following for you playbackStateBuilder:

```java
playbackStateBuilder.setActions(PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_SKIP_TO_NEXT 
        | PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_SKIP_TO_PREVIOUS);
```

For whatever reason the way you have it declaring the actions one after another like that doesn't work. I have no idea why. I struggled with this for literally two weeks and no one besides you my friend has posted a question about this. I'm hoping that whoever experiences this will be saved by my response and I hope it helps you too my friend! (: